# Crystal Reports : Filter value in Cross-tab

Tags: crystal-reports

My data looks like this:  For each department, there is a flag on each record if the record meets SLA.  The possible values are (SLA_Met, SLA_NotMet, Exclude).  Exclude means do not use these records in the % calculation .

```
         SLA_Met          SLA_NotMet     Excluded
           288                 3             12      
          98.97%             1.03%          4.03%
```

I have a cross-tab set up with SLA_Met in the Column section and the in the summarized fields I have the sum of the SLA Counts (288+3).  I am able to calculate the of SLA Met% = 288/291 = 98.97%; SLA_NotMet% =  3/291 = 1.03%, but it is also calculating the Excluded % = 12/291 = 4.03%.  I want to exclude the calculation of the Excluded %.

Can I do that in Crystal?  I tried to display the value of the SLA_Met column via an Embedded_Summary row in my cross-tab but it has value of 'Excluded' for all three columns.

Comment: Can you post your calculation formula and also can you explain how you design the cross tab

Comment: I created a variable (SLA_TOTAL) that is the sum of the SLA Met and SLA_NotMet.  In the Summarized Fields section of the cross-tab, I created an Embedded_Summary field with the following calculation:



Totext (100*(GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex, 0)/GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex, 2))) + '%'


.  This calculates the percentages but it does it for all three values (SLA_Met, SLA_NotMet, and Excluded).  I don't want it to do the calculation for the Excluded column

Answer (score 0):

Change your formula like this:

```
Totext (100*(GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex, 0)/GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex, 1))) + '%'
```